# Heroku Internal Server Error (Error has to do with mongoDB I think)

Tags: heroku

This is what comes up when I run heroku logs -t

```
2022-02-01T12:23:49.744081+00:00 app[web.1]: > ecommerce@1.0.0 start
2022-02-01T12:23:49.744081+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-01T12:23:49.744082+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-01T12:23:50.089404+00:00 app[web.1]: LISTENING ON PORT 3000
2022-02-01T12:23:50.208790+00:00 app[web.1]: DATABASE CONNECTED
2022-02-01T12:23:50.361356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-01T12:24:18.323977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-02-01T12:24:18.338851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-02-01T12:24:18.932047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-02-01T12:24:19.136709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-02-01T12:24:21.951819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-01T12:24:24.038796+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-01T12:24:24.038815+00:00 app[web.1]: > ecommerce@1.0.0 start
2022-02-01T12:24:24.038815+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-02-01T12:24:24.038815+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-01T12:24:24.888895+00:00 app[web.1]: LISTENING ON PORT 3000
2022-02-01T12:24:24.949303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-01T12:24:25.213934+00:00 app[web.1]: DATABASE CONNECTED
2022-02-01T12:24:54.889726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com request_id=b8fe8e92-23d0-46b4-8a84-792e16da6aee fwd="41.210.23.240" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28570ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2022-02-01T12:24:54.890004+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-02-01T12:24:54.890013+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
2022-02-01T12:24:54.890013+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
2022-02-01T12:24:54.890014+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

On the heroku app link i get a page which says "Internal Server Error"

In the console this is what i get

```
thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance. Any idea what is causing this ? I have connected my database via mongo atlas.

Comment: `2022-02-01T12:24:54.890004+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` Looks like your driver is trying to connect the DB on `localhost`. Sure you have a MongoDB running on the server?
You need to configure the DB Connection when your app is running on Heroku.

Comment: You're trying to connect to MongoDB on the server where your code is running. That won't work on Heroku. You're also listening on port 3000. That won't work either. Please [edit] your question to show both your MongoDB connection settings (don't show us passwords) and `index.js`.

Comment: Thank you ! I just noticed i forgot to change the mongostore. It was set to my local host.